# Getting deployment failed error in Azure API App after syncing with GitHub

Tags: azure, github, azure-api-apps

I updated the NuGet packages locally and pushed the changes to remote GitHub repo. My remote repo is connected with Azure API App. After this update, I am getting deployment failed error. Below are the logs I found on Azure.

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Under the App service on Azure portal, there is a **Console** link in the menu. I went to the path `D\home\site\repository` and then ran `nuget restore`. It updated the package references and my build was back to normal again.